Ejabberd / Swag(Nginx) / LetsEncrypt
So I have a "legacy" system composed of several pieces standing behind Swag/Nginx (Docker) as a reverse-proxy and it runs very smoothly. Swag integrates LetsEncrypt, which makes it easy setting up https encryption. Recently I have set up an XMPP server using Docker/Ejabberd. The Docker image also integrates LetsEncrypt and expects https to be set at the level of Ejabberd (as opposed to the other apps that send http flows to Nginx, who manages encryption). So I have set up Ejabberd to directly access the web without reverse-proxy. But when renewal is due for the certificate, I have to stop Swag, connect Ejabberd to port 80, renew, disconnect Ejabberd, reconnect Swag.
Does anyone have a trick that might serve the cert fetched by Docker/Swag to Docker/Ejabberd ?
I have looked at this tutorial but it is hard to apply to a dockerised context.
